# Access COM DLL using VS 2008 on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c#

I am using Windows 7 64 bit OS and VS 2008 SP1 as development environment.

One of the console application uses a COM component. When I try to create an instance of a class from the COM component, I got following error:

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {CE92C3B9-9A93-40E1-85AB-6A49170AEF7F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010105.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're building an managed .NET application from the fact that you added a C# tag to the question.
Managed applications are started in the as a 64-bit process unless you explicitly define it to be launched as a 32 bit application through ProjectProperties - Build - Platform Target.
If the COM component you're loading (in-process?) comes from a 32-bit native DLL then the instantiation will fail since you obviously cannot mix CPU models in 1 process.